# How to conflate consecutive gsubs in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I have the following

```
address.gsub(/^\d*/, "").gsub(/\d*-?\d*$/, "").gsub(/\# ?\d*/,"")
```

Can this be done in one gsub? I would like to pass a list of patterns rather then just one pattern - they are all being replaced by the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could combine them with an alternation operator (`|`):

```
address = '6 66-666 #99 11-23'
address.gsub(/^\d*|\d*-?\d*$|\# ?\d*/, "")
# " 66-666  "

address = 'pancakes 6 66-666 # pancakes #99 11-23'
address.gsub(/^\d*|\d*-?\d*$|\# ?\d*/,"")
# "pancakes 6 66-666 pancakes  "
```

You might want to add little more whitespace cleanup. And you might want to switch to one of:

```
/\A\d*|\d*-?\d*\z|\# ?\d*/
/\A\d*|\d*-?\d*\Z|\# ?\d*/
```

depending on what your data really looks like and how you need to handle newlines.

Comment: Perfect exactly what I was looking for. There are no newlines in the data.  Is it better to use \A and \Z instead of ^ and $?  They both work

Comment: @sanon: Depends on how you want to deal with embedded newlines. Basically, `^` and `$` match beginning and end of line but `\A` and `\z` (or `\Z`) match the beginning and end of the whole string.

Comment: But if there are no newlines it doesn't matter; `^` and `$` will do fine.

Comment: You may want to use [Regexp.union](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Regexp.html#M001225) if the number of alternatives grows a little large.

Answer (score 3):

Combining the regexes is a good idea--and relatively simple--but I'd like to recommend some additional changes. To wit:

```
address.gsub(/^\d+|\d+(?:-\d+)?$|\# *\d+/, "")
```

Of your original regexes, `^\d*` and `\d*-?\d*$` will *always* match, because they don't have to consume any characters.  So you're guaranteed to perform two replacements on every line, even if that's just replacing empty strings with empty strings.  Of my regexes, `^\d+` doesn't bother to match unless there's at least one digit at the beginning of the line, and `\d+(?:-\d+)?$` matches what looks like an integer-or-range expression at the end of the line.

Your third regex, `\# ?\d*`, will match any `#` character, and if the `#` is followed by a space and some digits, it'll take those as well.  Judging by your other regexes and my experience with other questions, I suspect you meant to match a `#` only if it's followed by **one** or more digits, with optional spaces intervening.  That's what my third regex does.

If any of my guesses are wrong, please describe what you were trying to do, and I'll do my best to come up with the right regex.  But I really don't think those first two regexes, at least, are what you want.

---

**EDIT** (in answer to the comment):  When working with regexes, you should always be aware of the distinction between a regex the *matches nothing* and a regex that *doesn't match*.  You say you're applying the regexes to street addresses.  If an address doesn't happen to start with a house number, `^\d*` will match nothing--that is, it will report a successful match, said match consisting of the empty string preceding the first character in the address.

That doesn't matter to you, you're just replacing it with another empty string anyway.  But why bother doing the replacement at all?  If you change the regex to `^\d+`, it will report a failed match and no replacement will be performed.  The result is the same either way, but the "matches noting" scenario (`^\d*`) results in a lot of extra work that the "doesn't match" scenario avoids.  In a high-throughput situation, that could be a life-saver.

The other two regexes bring additional complications: `\d*-?\d*$` could match a hyphen at the end of the string (e.g. `"123-"`, or even `"-"`); and `\# ?\d*` could match a hash symbol anywhere in string, not just as part of an apartment/office number.  You know your data, so you probably know neither of those problems will ever arise; I'm just making sure you're aware of them.  My regex `\d+(?:-\d+)?$` deals with the trailing-hyphen issue, and `\# *\d+` at least makes sure there are digits after the hash symbol.

Comment: I'm trying to take out everything in the address except street name, city and state.  I take any numbers off the front but stop at a space to leave numbered street names. I take numbers off the end (the zip codes) but some zips have a dash. The third one is to take out apt numbers which are either #9 or # 9.

I'm not sure what you mean by "will always match" - won't they only match digits?

Comment: Maybe I should have said they'll always **think** they matched. ;) I'll edit my answer to expand on that point.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you combine them together in a single gsub() regex, as an alternation,
it changes the context of the starting search position.

Example, each of these lines start at the beginning of the result of the previous
regex substitution.
`s/^\d*//g`
`s/\d*-?\d*$//g`
`s/\# ?\d*//g`

and this
`s/^\d*|\d*-?\d*$|\# ?\d*//g`
resumes search/replace where the last match left off and could potentially produce a different overall output, especially since a lot of the subexpressions search for similar
if not the same characters, distinguished only by line anchors.

I think your regex's are unique enough in this case, and of course changing the order
changes the result.